# ImportError: cannot import name 'LayerNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.no rmalization'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

In running a python project I get the following error. I installed various versions of tensorflow (from 2.2.3 to 2.4.1), but the problem is there... I don't know what I should change or what is the mismatch. It previously was working... please help if you know tensroflow

```
File "/home/pouramini/seqio/seqio/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line
 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py
", line 84, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/__in$
t__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/mode$
s.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import sequential
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engi$
e/sequential.py", line 24, in <module>
   from tensorflow.python.keras import layers as layer_module
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layer
s/__init__.py", line 149, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization import LayerNormalization
ImportError: cannot import name 'LayerNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.no
rmalization' (/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras
/layers/normalization/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Instead of ``from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization import LayerNormalization`` use ``from tensorflow.keras.layers import LayerNormalization``.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50004#issuecomment-854266470 kind of similar issue

Comment: @AmitGupta thanks, what was the solution there? it said install and uninstall solved the problem, install and unistalled of what?

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled `tensorflow` both by `conda remove tensorflow` and `pip uninstall tensorflow` and even removed the folder manually from `miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`

Then installed tensorflow (I tried 2.3.0) by `pip install tensorflow==2.3.0`

now the problem was resolved